# Remote desktop software for Android/Windows that runs well enough to be used for light gaming

Tags: windows, android, remote-access, remote-desktop

I'm looking for remote desktop software that lets me control a Windows machine from an Android tablet. I've looked around and tried a few things, but none of them do what I want to a usable degree.

It needs these features:

- Favors speed and performance over graphics. I don't mind if the colors look slightly off, but if it's choppy it's almost unusable.
- The Android touchscreen should act directly as the mouse. Tapping should act as clicking, touching and dragging should act as clicking and dragging. Panning and zooming isn't necessary, but if it's included, it should not be invasive.
- It must work within a VirtualBox VM. The VM has 2d and 3d accelleration turned on, it has 256 MB of video memory, and it has guest additions with DirectX support. The VM is also Windows 7. The games I intend to stream with this are not by any means graphically intensive, and they work fine on the VM.
- It has to be free or very cheap. Ads are acceptable.
- (Ideal but not required) It should transmit sound.

So far I've tried RDP, splashtop, and kainy. RDP was too choppy, splashtop wouldn't work without paying monthly, and kainy didn't work at all (showed a green screen and the mouse controls were completely broken).

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Not a direct recommendation (I'm not the Windows user nor the gamer) – but while waiting for good recommendations, be welcome seeing my list of apps to use your [Android Device as second Screen](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controlpc#group_652), [Access your computer via VNC](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controlpc#group_655) and the others on that same page. Should at least narrow down your search. Good luck!

Comment: @Izzy I'll definitely check those out. Thanks! I'll update my question if I find what I need.